# #noqa works only on one line import but not on import ()

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import, flake8

I have a list of imports I used in a file:

```
import (
a,
b,
c 
)
```

However, this imports are `@pytest.fixture` and thus, they are not called explicitly in the code and so I got *"imported but unused" Flake8 error*, as expected.

I tried to do the following:

1. use `as`, e.g.:

   ```
   import (
       a as a,
       b as b,
       ...
   )
   ```
2. add `#noqa` at each line end, e.g.:

   ```
   import (
       a, #noqa
       b, #noqa
       ...
   )
   ```
3. add `#noqa` at the end of the import, i.e.:

   ```
   import (
       ...
   ) #noqa
   ```

But none have worked. Only splitting the import into separate lines did the trick, i.e.

```
import a #noqa
import b #noqa
...
```

Why is that and am I missing a simpler way to do so?

Comment: I've edited your list items to contain multiline code blocks because the one liners were a bit unclear. Could you check to make sure I did it correctly, according to your original intent?

Comment: As an FYI, you can put a code block in a list item by indenting it a further for spaces.

Comment: yeah, its perfect. Thanks

Comment: Your last one is how you are supposed to import multiple modules anyway, according to Python's offical style-guide, [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports).

Comment: I'm really surprised that #3 doesn't work, but I guess they don't want you to clump good imports with bad when you check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your original code is a syntax error so I'm assuming you mean something like this:

```py
from mod import (
    a,
    b,
    c,
)
```

if you run this through flake8 you get:

```
$ flake8 t.py 
t.py:1:1: F401 'mod.a' imported but unused
t.py:1:1: F401 'mod.b' imported but unused
t.py:1:1: F401 'mod.c' imported but unused
```

to inline-disable lint codes, use a `# noqa` comment on the line where the error occurs (or if it is a triple quoted string or backslash-escaped string then use the last line) -- the former case applies here

```py
from mod import (  # noqa: F401
    a,
    b,
    c,
)
```

and:

```
$ flake8 t.py
$ echo $?
0
```

---

disclaimer: I'm the current flake8 maintainer